# Why isn't this anchor tag taking up 100% of the available space of its parent div?

Tags: html, anchor, css

My understanding leads me to believe that putting a `<a>` with the `display:block;` CSS property inside of a `<div>` is supposed to cause that entire div to "become" the link (IE anywhere I hover in the div, it is considered the link, because the link takes up 100% height and width).

That behavior doesn't seem to be working in the example below. If you'd rather `inspect element` and poke around yourself with the live code, you can view the site @: http://shayla.phasesolutions.ca/. See the nav at the top of the page for the issue I'm describing.

HTML:

```
    <header>
        <div class="logo"><a href="#"></a></div>
        <div class="nav-homepage"><a href="#"></a></div>
        <div class="nav-webdesign"><a href="#"></a></div>
        <div class="nav-graphicdesign"><a href="#"></a></div>
        <div class="nav-miscartwork"><a href="#"></a></div>
        <div class="nav-aboutme"><a href="#"></a></div>
        <div class="nav-contactme"><a href="#"></a></div>
    </header>
```

CSS:

```
header {
    .site-section;
    height: 125px;

    div {
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        top: 10px;

        a {
            display: block;
        }
    }

    div:first-child {
        position: relative;
        top: 0px;
    }
}
.nav-aboutme, .nav-contactme, .nav-graphicdesign, .nav-homepage, .nav-miscartwork, .nav-webdesign, .shadow, .homepage-nav-aboutme, .homepage-nav-contactme, .homepage-nav-graphicdesign, .homepage-nav-miscartwork, .homepage-nav-webdesign, .logo{
    background: url(/resource/img/sprites.png) no-repeat;
}

.nav-aboutme {
    background-position: -81px -361px ;
    width: 76px;
    height: 105px;
    margin-right: 49px;
}

.nav-contactme {
    background-position: 0 -360px ;
    width: 76px;
    height: 105px;
}

.nav-graphicdesign {
    background-position: -79px -246px ;
    width: 89px;
    height: 105px;
    margin-right: 49px;
}

.nav-homepage {
    background-position: 0 -245px ;
    width: 76px;
    height: 105px;
    margin-right: 49px;
}

.nav-miscartwork {
    background-position: -79px -132px ;
    width: 85px;
    height: 105px;
    margin-right: 49px;
}

.nav-webdesign {
    background-position: 0 -132px ;
    width: 76px;
    height: 105px;
    margin-right: 49px;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe its because the block element has no content inside of it. If you add a letter inside the anchor link the anchor link will become 100% of the width of the div.

If you add width:100% and height:100% it will take up the entire div.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason I seem to remember trying adding `height: 100%; width: 100%;` to it before, and it not working... turns out I'm just an idiot. It worked fine. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

100% of 0 is 0. You need your `div` to have content, then:

```
a{
  display:block; height:100%; width:100%;
}
```